# Does cache in Linux can cause heap memory out of space exception?

Tags: linux, caching, jvm

I am facing an issue while deploying a particular application onto the Linux server running Ubuntu 16.04.

The application is written in Java, and performs a lot of I/O operation. In due course of time, while running the application, the cache consumption will increases. Although the output of `free -h` will show sufficient amount of `available memory`, but the application will crash by throwing the exception `Java Heap Memory Out of Space Exception`.

To work around the problem, I execute the clear cache command to free up the cache. 
I need some guidance on whether the issue is caused by the cache, or something is wrong while running the application, as clearing the cache won't let the exception happen. Do Cache take away JVM memory?

Comment: No, you need to tweak the JVM heap size to have an effect. You're probably running the application with a too small heap, or you've wrote the application to use way too much memory than necessary (the default heap goes pretty far, unless you're writing memory wasteful code).

Comment: I don't have control on the code, so I can't change it, I will go with tweaking JVM parameters. What is the default heap size per application?

Comment: Smaller of 1/4th of the physical memory or 1GB. So unless you're working with older hardware, 1GB.

Answer (score 0):

Linux will always free the cache as needed, you should never have to do this explicitly.

> the application will crash by throwing the exception Java Heap Memory Out of Space Exception

This means there isn't enough swap space to allocate memory to the JVM's heap.

I would either

- increase the swap space
- decrease the heap size.
- pretouch all the spaces to ensure they are allocated eagerly.

Comment: Swap space is around 11gb, I was able to fix it by increasing heap memory using Java command line arguments. Swap is almost free.